# How do I render snippets that represent ui components in pages on Wagtail CMS?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I am new to wagtail and i'm working on a project to build a cms. The cms will have some ui components like NavBars and cards that i am making throught snippets, so that i can reuse them in diferent pages (or even on the same page).

My question is what's the best aproach to render this items? I thought of using templatetags, but i am not complete sure if thats a good idea.
What do you think its a nice and clean way of doing this?